# How to match two sets of data using Tensorflow

Tags: node.js, tensorflow

I need to match some data to the closest match in a database. I currently have a function which uses lots of different if/else statements but I am only getting an pass rate of around 60% and am trying to work out how to improve this. Is machine learning an answer if I train a model to find the best match? If so could someone point me in the direction of a good tutorial for this?

As an example my dataset could be like this;

```
const data = {
    number=43
    sub-number=null
    name="BULL"
    category=""
}

const database = [
{
    number=43
    sub-number=null
    name="BULL"
    category=""
}
.. some other objects
]
```

This example is an easy match however there are some instances where the data object above could need to match with;

```
const database = [
{
    number="43 BULL"
    sub-number=null
    name=null
    category=""
}

]
```

In summary, there are too many different possibilities for me to write a if/else statement to catch them all, however, the data when viewed by a person is very easy to match so i'm hoping by training a model it would have a good pass rate. I'm not sure if tensorflow is appropriate for this as the examples i've seen seem to be image related

Answer (score 0):

Try this code might help. It compare whole object if their all values are equal try once on typescript playground.

```
    interface D {
    v: number,
    sub: null,
    name: string,
    category: string
}

const data: D = {
    v: 43,
    sub: null,
    name: "BULL",
    category: ""
}

const database: D[] = [
    {
        v: 43,
        sub: null,
        name: "BULL",
        category: ""
    }
]

for (const db of database) {
    if (JSON.stringify(data) === JSON.stringify(db)) {
        console.log("They are equal");
    }
    else {
        console.log("They are not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem due to the way the datasets can be matched, see the examples I posted

Comment: number can be string also in database array     number="43 BULL"?